# How can I upgrade openshift origin if it is run as a docker container?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

According to [the document](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container), all configuration and stored application definitions will also be removed when a container is removed if openshift origin runs as [a docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin/).

My question is is there way to upgrade openshift without losing the configurations if I am running the container?

Comment: Probably using data volume containers: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Dockerfile, use the original image as a base image an run your update statements.

```
FROM openshift/origin

RUN your-update-statement

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/openshift"]
```

After that just build and run your Docker image. For more info see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/